# Solr lengthNorm is not working correctly

Tags: solr, lucene

Im using 4.6.0. thought its a great search engine Im having troubles enabling my lengthNorm in Order to score doc with shorters word in field.

**1.** The term Im serching for is "lemon".

**2.** Im want to score products with less words in the "name" field higher

**3.** The result 2 first products are:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "lowercaseOperators": "true",
      "fl": "name,score",
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "lemon",
      "qf": "name",
      "_": "1457866062982",
      "stopwords": "true",
      "wt": "json",
      "defType": "edismax",
      "rows": "2"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 350,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 2.6099632,
    "docs": [
      {
        "name": "Fairway Lemon Fruit Slices",
        "score": 2.6099632
      },
      {
        "name": "Fairway Lemon Heads",
        "score": 2.6099632
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can see my problem is that I want the second product who has 3 words will get higher score than the first one who has 4 words in name

**4.** I have tried to omitNorm="false" for the field type in schema.xml
here is my lines from schema.xml:

```
<!-- like text_en_splitting but indexing stop words and indexing synonyms -->



 <fieldType name="text_en_splitting_unblocked" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <!-- charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/ -->
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!--- filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="false"/-->

        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/><!-- try expand="true"  -->
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <!-- charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/ -->
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/  --><!-- try expand="true"  -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/><!-- was false  --> 
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" catenateWords="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

And :

```
<field name="name" type="text_en_splitting_unblocked" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Tried both stored="true" or stored="false"
Noticed that nothing changed in the schema broweser
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/#/collection1/schema-browser?field=name
Name was still stored in all
Properties
Schema
Index
(V for all of them)

Index Analyzer:
org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain
Query Analyzer:
org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain

I have tried to reindexand did "service solr restart"
but still the score stays the same.
Maybe the score is the same because the check for shorter fields done after the tokenization?
If so, how can I change that?
Please help me

Comment: Add debugQuery=true to your query to get the scores for each factor. And you'll have to reindex after changing anything related to omitNorms, so be sure to actually do that (and confirm that all the documents have been indexed again) - nuke the index to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I debug the query. and did reindex.
Found an explenation just posted an answer to it..
P.S what do you mean by "nuke the index to be sure"?

Comment: To delete everthing in the index, for example by removing the data directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lucene fieldNorm discrepancy between Similarity calculation and query-time value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135872/lucene-fieldnorm-discrepancy-between-similarity-calculation-and-query-time-value)